# Как вывести данные из базы EAV в таблицу?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, yii2, eav

Есть база EAV с таблицами:
**product** - продукты (ключ: product_id);
**params** - параметры продуктов (ключи: product_id, param_id);
**value** - значения параметров продуктов (ключ: param_id)

Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести в плоскую таблицу набор параметров продуктов например такого вида:

```
product_id | param_id1 | param_id2 | param_id3
1          | value1    | value2    | value3
2          | value1    | value2    | value3
3          | value1    | value2    | value3
```

Comment: Количество свойств зависит от типа продукта или может быть рандомным для каждого продукта?

Comment: да, например: телевизор и обувь со своими характеристиками

Comment: Тогда у вас в наличии должна быть таблица со списком полей для каждого типа товара, соответственно выбираете все эти свойства и на основании типа товара генерируете запрос на подобие того что привёл Akina где каждый Join будет включать таблицу value для каждого свойства товара после конструирования запроса вам останется его выполнить и получить каждый тип товара со всем их свойствами.

Comment: Приблизительно должно получится так: https://habrahabr.ru/post/45935/ только в вашем случае это будет обёрнуто в цикл по типу товара

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t0.product_id
     , t1.value param_id1
     , t2.value param_id2
     , t3.value param_id3
-- остальные параметры
FROM product t0
LEFT /* or INNER */ JOIN params t01 ON t0.product_id = t01.product_id
      LEFT /* or INNER */ JOIN value t1 ON t01.param_id = t1.param_id
LEFT /* or INNER */ JOIN params t02 ON t0.product_id = t02.product_id
      LEFT /* or INNER */ JOIN value t2 ON t02.param_id = t2.param_id
LEFT /* or INNER */ JOIN params t03 ON t0.product_id = t03.product_id
      LEFT /* or INNER */ JOIN value t3 ON t03.param_id = t3.param_id
-- остальные копии таблиц
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую